# How do I call a filter method when array is updated

Tags: angular

I've created a service that gets a list of job objects from a http api. In a consuming view component (ticket-adder) I want to call a method that filters the list, and I need to call this when every the main list (jobs) is updated. This is because the the main jobs list seems to be called asynchronously and is empty when (tick-adder) first loads and GetJobs() is called.

ticket-adder.component

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, RequestMethod, Request } from "@angular/http";
import { JobBase, Employee, WorkCategory, TimeEntryApi } from "./models";
import { JobService } from "./job.service";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { NgbModal, NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
    selector: 'ticket-adder',
    templateUrl: './app/ticket-adder.html',    
    providers: [JobService]
})

export class TicketAdderComponent implements OnInit {

    activeJobs: Array<JobBase> = [];
    @Input() name;


    constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal, public http: Http, private jobServ: JobService) {

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getJobs();

    }

    getJobs(): void {
       this.activeJobs = this.jobServ.jobs.filter(x => x.status > 9).map(blah => new JobBase(blah.id, blah.jobName, blah.jobNumber));
    }   
}
```

job.service

```
import { Component, Input, Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, RequestMethod, Request } from "@angular/http";
import { JobBase, JobMore } from "./models";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs'
import { List } from 'immutable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class JobService {

    public jobs: Array<JobMore> = [];

    constructor(public http: Http) {
        this.GetJobs();
    }

    GetJobs() {

        this.http.get('./api/job')
            .map(res => (<Response>res).json())
            .map((jobs1: Array<any>) => {
                let result: Array<JobMore> = [];
                if (jobs1) {
                    jobs1.forEach(j => {
                        result.push(
                            new JobMore(
                                j.id,
                                j.jobName,
                                j.jobNumber,
                                j.status
                            ));
                    });
                }

                return result;
            }).
            subscribe(
            data => {
                this.jobs = data;
                console.log(this.jobs);
            },
            err => console.log("Jobs API Call: ", err)
            );
    }

}
```

EDIT:

This is as far as I've gotten. I'm getting an error at runtime "result.filter(...).map(...).toArray is not a function"

(ticket-adder)

```
getJobs(): void {
    //this.jobServ.GetJobs();
    //this.activeJobs = this.jobServ.jobs.filter(x => x.status > 9).map(blah => new JobBase(blah.id, blah.jobName, blah.jobNumber));

    this.jobServ.GetJobs().subscribe(
        result => this.activeJobs = result.filter(x => x.status > 9).map(blah => new JobBase(blah.id, blah.jobName, blah.jobNumber)).toArray(),
        error => console.error,
        () => console.log('completed function here or remove ')
    );

    this.Submitted = this.activeJobs.length.toString();
}
```

(job.service)

```
public jobs: List<JobMore>;

GetJobs(): Observable<List<JobMore>>{
    return this.http.get('./api/job')
        .map(this.JobsResponseMapper)

    /*this.http.get('./api/job')
        .map(res => (<Response>res).json())
        .map((jobs1: Array<any>) => {
            let result: Array<JobMore> = [];
            if (jobs1) {
                jobs1.forEach(j => {
                    result.push(
                        new JobMore(
                            j.id,
                            j.jobName,
                            j.jobNumber,
                            j.status
                        ));
                });
            }

            return result;
        });
    */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because http.get is called asynchronous, activeJobs is set before jobs is set in your service, therefore activeJobs will be empty

In your service I see you do a lot of mapping and subscribe. I would suggest not to do subscribe your service and change your code as below.

ticket.adder:

```
getJobs(): void {
     this.jobServ.GetJobs().subscribe(
        result => this.activeJobs = result.filter(...),
        error => console.error,
        () => console.log('completed function here or remove ')
     )
}
```

job.service

```
    GetJobs() {
        this.http.get('./api/job')
            .map(MyResponseMapper)
    }

MyResponseMapper(response: Response) {
    data = response.json();
    //do whatever with data
    return data;
}
```

In the code above `activeJobs` will be set with the data returned from GetJobs().

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm having some issue implementing this. see edited question.

Comment: I would suggest to write the output to console each time by adding some code until you get the expected result, after then set this.activeJobs with the result. For example start with `result => console.log(resul)`, then add `.filter(...)`, etc. What I think why you get the error is because you try to create an array from an array (I assume that `blah` is an array because you apply filter). Second `map` will not perform a loop and therefore `id`, `jobNumber` and `jobType` will be empty, you should put `blah` manually in a loop.

Comment: here is also a plunker example: https://plnkr.co/edit/pIOaQNxNgmmp7NFropXt?p= (btw map() puts the data in a loop. my fault)

Comment: .map and .fitler are returning an Iterable<number, JobMore> not Array<JobMore>. So I was trying to convert it to an array with toArray(); but it results in an error saying it is not a function.

Comment: Also in the blah is a JobMore object, not an array. Atleast it is supposed to be.